# When to use square brackets in Chrome manifest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, brackets

What do they represent?  Where is this documented?  For example,

```
...
  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css" :  ["inject.css"],
      "js": ["filter.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }],
...
```

or

```
...
  "permissions": [
    "file://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
  ],
...
```

How do I know if this shouldn't be , for example,

```
...
  "permissions": [
    ["file://*/*"],
    ["tabs"],
    ["storage"],
    ["activeTab"]
  ],
...
```

though the better example is illustrated with the seemingly bizarre form of the content_script key's value.  It appears as if the key is being assigned an array and that array sometimes contains single  elements or sometimes it hold merely strings or even a Boolean value.  Are the brackets not representing arrays?  Do they represent perhaps an index?  An index into tabs?

Comment: [Manifest File Format. Every extension has a JSON-formatted manifest file, named manifest.json, that provides important information](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest). Please read up on what JSON format is.

Comment: Hi SHKaper.  I am fairly new to all of this, but I have been familiar with the JSON format for quite sometime.  Am I missing some basic understanding of the JSON format that provides insight into when Chrome expects an array and when Chrome expects a string and when Chrome expects a boolean as a value in a key-value pair?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see where the confusion lies now. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome extension manifest follows the JSON format, which means that square brackets represent an array of some sort. The [Manifest file format docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) explicitly state when the field value should be an array and when it shouldn't. For example,

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {...},
```

means that the value of `chrome_url_overrides` *must* be an object (denoted by `{...}`), while

```
"content_scripts": [{...}],
```

means that the value of `content_scripts` *must* be an array of objects. Even if you only have a single content script defined there, it's still expected to be enclosed in an array.

Regarding your example of `permissions`, here's what the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) says:

> Each permission can be either one of a list of known strings (such as
>   "geolocation") or a match pattern

It never says "can be a list of lists of strings". Moreover, the example on the docs page further illustrates that it's just an array of strings, not an array of arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The bracket just means it's an array. Sometimes it contains only one element, but brackets are still needed.

Comment: Thank you Chad.  That is what I suspected, but in Google's Chrome Extension Developer references, I cannot find anything that explicitly states where a manifest entry is to be an array or key-value pair with the value being a boolean or a string or an  array.  To make matters even more confusing, if the Content-Script is not listed with brackets, the manifest is rejected by Chrome.  Also adding to the confusion is Chrome behaving differently if a permission is listed as a string or bracketed.  I have found I need permissions bracketed for certain permissions to be granted.